# Is there a way to script adding a ssh public/private key to the Jenkins credentials plugin without using the GUI interface

Tags: jenkins, ansible

Hi so I'm trying to script setting up a jenkins instance completely without using the web interface using ansible and geerlinguy.jenkins ansible playbooks.   I've been searching to see if there is a way to add a credential (ssh private/public key pair ) in order to add a node.

I can do all this via the web interface I just don't want to, I need to be able to script this so it can be a repeatable processes without human intervention.

is there any way to do this, I've found this previous stack overflow question but has anyone figured out another way of doing it?

[I want to create jenkins credentials via ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35025829/i-want-to-create-jenkins-credentials-via-ansible)

Comment: Why do you need another way than the ones already provided by your link?

Comment: I basically am not satisfied with the ways listed in the other link.  using the jenkins api is doable but seems to be a bit more complicated than it needs to be.  I'm leaning more towards the new plugin: https://jenkins.io/projects/jcasc/  jenkins configuration as code.  Seems to be the best modern way of setting things up now.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this via jenkins API using the Ansible URI module.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/uri_module.html#uri-module

I don't know how the jenkins API works or anything, but here is a snippit of an API call I put together for phpipam.

```
 - name: check if login works
  uri:
    url: "{{ url }}"
    method: GET
    user: "{{ user }}"
    password: "{{ password }}"
    force_basic_auth: yes
    status_code: 200,404, 400
    timeout: 10
    validate_certs: false
    headers: "{{ token }}"
  register: result

- name: debug
  debug:
    var: result
```